# App crashes android development

Tags: android, json

Hi I am building a login app in where the details of the users will be shown using JSON PHP and MYSQL but whenever the profile would show up it crashes what Am I doing wrong? What's weird is that this was working few days ago

logcat report

```
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at com.example.itmaproject.EditContactsActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditContactsActivity.java:144)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-05 18:55:34.088: E/AndroidRuntime(3173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my codepackage com.example.itmaproject;
    public class EditContactsActivity extends Activity {

```
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtNumber;
    TextView txtAbout;
    TextView txtDate;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;
    TextView txtDepart;
    TextView fullname;
    TextView  txtUser;
    Button btnLogout;
    String username;
    SessionManager session;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_contact_details = "http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/login/get_contact_details.php";

    // url to update product
    private static final String url_update_contact = "http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/login/get_contact_details.php";

    // url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_contact = "http://10.0.3.2/sunshine-ems/delete_contact.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
    private static final String TAG_DEPART = "department";
    private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "lastname";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "user_id";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_contact);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);


        // save button


        // getting product details from intent
        //Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        //pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_USERNAME);
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        username = session.getUsername();
        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Launching All products Activity
                session.logoutUser();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditContactsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading contact details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_contact_details, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Contact Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray contactObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject contact = contactObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtDepart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.department);
                            //txtAbout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
                             txtUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            // display product data in EditText
                            String fullname = contact.getString(TAG_LASTNAME)+' '+ contact.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                            txtName.setText(fullname);
                            txtDepart.setText(contact.getString(TAG_DEPART));
                            //txtAbout.setText(contact.getString(TAG_LASTNAME));
                            txtUser.setText(contact.getString(TAG_ID));

                            Log.v("blahhhhh", "blah hhhhblah");

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                            Log.v("blah", "blah blah");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditContactsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving contact ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            //String number = txtNumber.getText().toString();
            //String about = txtAbout.getText().toString();
            String user = txtUser.getText().toString();
            String depart = txtDepart.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_USERNAME, username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_FIRSTNAME, name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DEPART, depart));
            //params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_LASTNAME, about));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ID, user));
            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_contact,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     * */
    class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditContactsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Contact...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_contact, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete Contact", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // product successfully deleted
                    // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
```

Line 141

```
Log.d("Single Contact Details", json.toString());
```

Comment: please paste the complete logcat

Comment: the solution is simple.Your "json" must be null.

Comment: Well, apparently `json` is `null` at this stage. Look at the response which your server sends back to the application, you make have an issue here. Or you may be sending the wrong request to the server. Or JSONParser may return null due to the some internal issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your url JSON may be null because of it

Comment: sorry for the late update. well anyway yeah it turns out the url i'm directing was wrong. I can't believe it was that simple >.< thanks for the help